# Property [client] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I can't get the value of the foreign key that is inside the booking table.

**Booking Table**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class booking extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'bookingID';
   protected $fillable = ['clientID', 'checkInDate', 'checkOutDate', 'roomsCount', 'roomTypeID', 'adultsCount', 'childrenCount', 'amenityID', 'paymentID'];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class,'clientID');
    }

}
```

**Client Table**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class client extends Model
{
  protected $primaryKey = 'clientID';
   protected $fillable = ['fullNmae', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress'];
  public function booking()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
  }
}
```

I tried adding the `protected $primaryKey = 'bookingID';` and   `protected $primaryKey = 'clientID';` as suggested in my previous question but now I still can't  get just the FirstName from the client table.

```
$bookingDetail = booking::with('client')->get();
    return  $bookingDetail->client->firstName;
```

Comment: your class name is `client` but you are using `Client` and same goes for `booking` in your relations. `$this->hasOne(Client::class,'clientID')`??

Comment: triend changing to `client` but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a property from a collection in these lines:

```
$bookingDetail = booking::with('client')->get();
return  $bookingDetail->client->firstName;
```

but this property `client` is defined for object, not a collection. so to solve it you must take one object from the collection like the following:

```
$bookingDetail = booking::with('client')->first();
return  $bookingDetail->client->firstName;
```

Comment: The problem with this is it's not getting the right client for that specific booking. It just get the first data on the booking table. Do i need to put a where statement?

Comment: it gets the first `booking` with the related `client`. what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I'm searching for the booking number and then returning the result of that booking data to the view.

Comment: yea, you should filter your result using where clause.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you need to try this one:

in your booking model:
// 'App\Client' these is example you need to put your client model path

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client','clientID');
    }
```

in your client model:

```
public function booking()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Booking' , 'clientID');
  }
```

Comment: $bookingDetail = booking::with('client')->get();
    return  $bookingDetail->client->firstName;     //in controller you  write class booking:  but its Booking